# Is it possible to show the following without the assumption of continuity in a closed inteval?

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

Let $f(x)$ be diffrentiable at $(a,b)$ for $a,b\in  \mathbb{R}$. given that $f'(x)\neq 0$ for any $x\in (a,b)$ proove that $f(x)=0$ for not more than one point in $(a,b)$

Well, If I was given that $f(x)$ is also continus at $[a,b]$ I could easly show that with a contradiction to rolle's theorem.

Is it possible to show that without the given about the continuity? or there is a mistake in the question?

Comment: Apply RT to $[c,d]$ if both $c$ and $d$ are zeroes of $f$ in $(a,b)$ with $c<d$.

Comment: You right, thank you very much!